# parsing .xml blast output with re

Tags: python, xml, parsing, blast

I'm trying to parse BLAST output in XML format using `re`, have never done it before, below is my code.

However,since some hits have `Hsp_num` sometimes more than once, I get more results for `query_from` and `query_to`, and less for `query_len`, how to specify that if `Hsp_num` is more than 1 do `print query_len` for it again? thank you

```
import re
output = open('result.txt','w')
n = 0
with open('file.xml','r') as xml:
    for line in xml:
         if re.search('<Hsp_query-from>', line) != None:
             line = line.strip()
             line = line.rstrip()
             line = line.strip('<Hsp_query-from>')
             line = line.rstrip('</')
             query_from = line
         if re.search('<Hsp_query-to>', line) != None:
             line = line.strip()
             line = line.rstrip()
             line = line.strip('<Hsp_query-to>')
             line = line.rstrip('</')
             query_to = line
         if re.search('<Hsp_num>', line) != None:
             line = line.strip()
             line = line.rstrip()
             line = line.strip('<Hsp_num>')
             line = line.rstrip('</')
             Hsp_num = line
             print >> output, Hsp_num+'\t'+query_from+'\t'+query_to
output.close()
```

I did `query_len` in a separate file, since it didnt work..

```
with open('file.xml','r') as xml:
    for line in xml:
        if re.search('<Iteration_query-len>', line) != None:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = line.strip('<Iteration_query-len>')
            line = line.rstrip('</')
            query_len = line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with [Biopython](http://biopython.org)? Its [`Bio.Blast.NCBIXML`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Blast.NCBIXML-module.html) module may be just what you need. [Chapter 7](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec94) of the Tutorial and Cookbook is all about BLAST, and section 7.3 deals with parsing. You'll get an idea of how it works, and it will be a lot easier than using regex to parse XML, which will only lead to tears and [mental breakdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: thank you,I had a look at that Chapter, seems to be complicated anyway, I think I am going to give up on parsing .XML format and work with tabular one. Was just wondering if this kind of thing is possible with re